# How to measure the size of base 64 image?

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I have an image already encoded in base64, how can I determin how big this object is. I want to tell the user of an application, if this file will take very long to transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have encoded to a Base64 string, then the size that you're transferring across the wire is simply the count of the characters.  Since Base64 fits within the character space of ASCII, your bytes across the wire are simply:

```
var bytes = encodedString.length
```

If size is a major concern, you probably want to consider not Base64 encoding your images.  Base64 will translate every 6 bits into an 8 bit character representation.  This means that you multiply the original by 4/3 when you Base64 encode.